# Search dictionary key in a column of sentences python

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I was trying to find if a dictionary key is contained in a sentence stored in a column of a data frame. Here an example.
I have the following dictionary:

```
dictionary = {"yellow":1234, "light blue":112, "orange":34,'blue':1}
```

And the following data frame:

```
df_data = {"sentence": ["the summarine is yellow", "the sky was an amazing light blue, you should have see it", 
" the grass is green", "why you face is purpule?"], "extra":['a','b','c','d'] }
df = pd.DataFrame(df_data)
```

Do you have an idea on how can I search for the dictionary key inside each sentence? If then the key is find I will save it in a new column, but this should not be a problem.
I had a similar problem in the past but the key was number and with .map() I was able to find it. I tried to use the same method now but is not working.
One thing that concerned me is the fact that the dictionary key may be composed of multiple words like in the case of "light blue" and I can not split each sentence in word and then search for the key because I will not be able to find the correct key.

Comment: What does your expected output look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- extract the keys from the sentence via `extract`
- use the `map` to fetch the values of the key from the `dictionary`.

```
df['new_col'] = df.sentence.str.extract(pat = f"({'|'.join(dictionary.keys())})")[0].map(dictionary)
```

##### OUTPUT:

```
                                            sentence extra  new_col
0                            the summarine is yellow     a   1234.0
1  the sky was an amazing light blue, you should ...     b    112.0
2                                 the grass is green     c      NaN
3                           why you face is purpule?     d      NaN
```

Comment: What if I have in the same sentence multiple keys can I use the same reasoning?

Answer (score 2):

You can concatenate them with an "or" operator (`|`):

```py
patterns = '|'.join(dictionary.keys())
df.sentence.str.contains(patterns)
```

Output:

```
0     True
1     True
2    False
3    False
Name: sentence, dtype: bool
```